# Spring-STS selenium usage NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

Hello i am having trouble with selenium-standalone-server. More on my understanding is the problem. I am confused as to why i need to reference it on my project (buildpath). See my source below

**BrowserService.java**

```
public void start() throws MalformedURLException{
    System.out.println("Staring browser...");
    System.out.println("Execute RemoteDriver: "+config.isRemote());
    if (config.isRemote()){
        System.out.println("Starting as RemoteWebDriver execution...");
        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.0.102:5555/wd/hub"),
                DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Starting as WebDriver execution...");
    }
}
```

**Console Log**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
    at com.at.regression.service.BrowserService.start(BrowserService.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.at.regression.RegressionToolApplication.run(RegressionToolApplication.java:26) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:776) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:760) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at com.at.regression.RegressionToolApplication.main(RegressionToolApplication.java:20) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    ... 7 common frames omitted
```

Whenever i try to reference `selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar` the above error will not occur. So why is that? Isn't this jar file use for starting remote drivers? like so

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role hub

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.0.102:4444/grid/register/ -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=./chromedriver.exe
```

**UPDATES**

changed my tags from selenium specific to spring, springtoolsuite specific. It has been ruled out from selenium side that this is not an issue with selenium. See the answer for details

Comment: In which version of standalone Selenium version are you observing the error?

Comment: hmm 2.53.0? if there are other version besides the one on the name please do point me where. btw if im not referencing the jar file the errors occurs and if im going to refrence it the error does not occur

Comment: I think this was working perfectly on 2.53.0 The issue is on 3.4.0

Comment: which jar/dependency are you referring to on version 3.4.0? sorry but i need to clarify as to what dependency are you referring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benifit of everybody. I have found the cause of this problem.

With the help from selenium guys in their github [Selenium 3.4.0 RemoteWebDriver NoClassDefFoundError](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3948). As you can see i was pointed to the issue of having a problem with my classpath. No matter how i investigated it i can't seem to find the part hat cause the classpath error. So what i did was change IDE.

When i encountered the error i was using STS (Spring Tool Suite). This is where i encountered the classpath error. Now, i  decided to change to Eclipse 4.6.3(neon) and the error was fixed. I only need to include selenium-server 3.4.0 dependency on my maven. Until someone who has time to go further investigating the STS issue. This will suffice for now.

As to the reason for the classpath error, currently i have no clue as to why it happened all i can think of is there must be some issue within the IDE itself. I did not go further since Eclipse worked for me.

As for the selenium-standalone-server-.jar, i still believe that this is not meant to be referenced within your project since this is used for starting up some remote drivers. selenium-server can already accommodate those classes that are needed

Hope this helps

**UPDATES**

as i was planning on posting this on Git as suggested by @Kris on the commetns below when i encountered a fix (sort of). As i was gathering data to be posted on Git, i performed a clean up on .m2/repository folder, i deleted all the contents and let the project build itself again. The error never occurred. Now, this maybe a maven problem so just updated it here for the benifit of everyone

Comment: Glad you solved it. Without more information about your project there is not much we (STS developers) can do to try and understand what is going on with your classpath. As is usually the case with classpath issues, the devil is in the details. So without some kind of sample project demonstrating the problem its going to be impossible to diagnose / fix. If you have a project that shows the problem, please consider creating a bug report (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues) and attach it.

Comment: Ohh i see will do. Anytime this weekend